# Migrate a Development MySQL database to a Production database

Tags: database, database-design, mysql

I need to be able to make changes to my development DB, 
Such as adding a table or so adding a column.

Is it possible to take this new DB schema and merge it or diff-&-merge it with the production DB without having to rebuild/repopulate the production database?

any tips welcome.

Comment: yea that would be great but $$$ and this is more of a side project, the budget doesnt contain more than a pizza or two =P

Comment: since the budget is low, might as well spent less effort ?

Comment: Even costly tools seem to do it quite badly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to keep track of your ALTER's and CREATE's in a file.

For example, if I were to add a column to a table on the development db, I would copy paste the sql I used into a file called `migrate.sql`. I would keep doing this until I'm ready to migrate to production.

At this point the file would be a series of sql statements that could be run in order on the production db to "sync" it with the development environment.

If you're not writing the raw queries yourself, you can probably get the commands being run out of whatever GUI tool you're using.

Comment: You can also get the appropriate ALTER TABLE statements in many GUI tools. You just need to be careful when editing tables.